# multiple radio buttons forms with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that will be presented multiple times dynamically with php depending on the amount of data from the database. 
For our example let's say that we have 2 objects and by that we have 2 similar forms. for example:

```
<form name="form1">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn btn-danger" value="no" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Not going
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn btn-success" value="maybe" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Maybe
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn btn-success" value="going" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Going
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</form>
```

My current jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio").change(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        var form1 = $('input:radio[name=options]:checked').val();
        var form2 = $('input:radio[name=options2]:checked').val();
        console.log("option 1:" + form1);
        console.log("option 2:" + form2);
    });
});
```

as you can see I am creating a new var to be assigned with each form value. 
I am looking for a build to build this dynamically based on the amount of forms created without having to create a var for each form hardcoded.

Thanks,

Nimi

Comment: it's no php question

Comment: Your probably right, but I am using php to create the form dynamically in my code. so I taught the solution might have to do something with passing the loop number from php to jquery.

Comment: for what you need get radio checked value?

Comment: each time a radio button is selected per form I want to get the form name and radio selected value and update the DB. That's my plan eventually.

Comment: Inside the event handler, `this.form.name` would be the name of the form, and `this.value` would be the value of the checked radio button !

Comment: You can just serialize https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ form and send to server by `ajax` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You can create an array and load all selected radio buttons in it. the `jQuery` code will be something like this:`var myArray = $('input:radio:checked'); console.log(myArray.length);`. Then you can iterate through the array and do what you need to do. Please give it a try and if you had more questions edit your post with the updated info